# PHP errors on get_field() WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get to grips with developing in WordPress. I have a basic understanding of PHP, but I'm aware the syntax is slightly different when developing in WordPress.

**Scenario**:

To ensure my PHP code works, I ran the following test:

```html
// define query
$args = array('post_type' => 'case-studies' );
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);


// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { // check, does the query have posts?
 echo '<ul>';
 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  $the_query->the_post(); 
  echo '<li>' .get_the_title() . '</li>'; // spits out page title
 }
    
 echo '</ul>';
 /* Restore original Post Data */
 wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
 // no posts found
}
```

Which works, it echo's the page title on the front end.

Now, In WordPress, I've created a new field group through `custom fields`:

[image]

In the same file as above, I've written the following

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $case-study-heading = get_field('case_study_heading');
    $case-study-subheading = get_field('case_study_subheading');
    $case-study-backgroung = get_field('case_study_background');
    $case-study-play = get_field('case_study_play_button');

    echo $case-study-heading;
} else {
    echo "no posts";
}
```

Which shows a **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='** on this line:

```
$case-study-heading = get_field('case_study_heading');
```

Usually in PHP I would do the above query like so:

```
$query = mysqli_query ("SELECT * FROM table_name"){
    $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query);
        $case-study-heading         = results['field_name'];
        $case-study-subheading      = results['field_name']; 


        if($results!=0) {
                echo "<ul>
                          <<li>$case-study-heading<li>
                          <li>$case-study-subheading</li>
                       </ul>";
        } else{
            echo "no rows in db";
        }
}
```

Am I executing WP PHP incorrectly? If so, ideas on why I'm getting a parse error?

**P.s.** I've seen the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) here. I've adapted my code to match it i.e. `$variable = get_field('field_name');` but still get the same error?

**Edit**: I've amended my WP PHP code after Will's comment:

```html
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $case_study_heading = get_field('case_study_heading');
    $case_study_subheading = get_field('case_study_subheading');
    $case_study_backgroung = get_field('case_study_background');
    $case_study_play = get_field('case_study_play_button');
    
    echo $case_study_heading;
} else {
    echo "no posts";
}
```

Now, upon running this, I don't see any errors (good!) but, nothing shows at all? not even the `else`, meaning the `if statement` is working?

I have got text in those fields in WP:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: PHP variables cannot have a dash but underscores. $my_var is valid but $my-var is not

Comment: @Willi, ah yeahh - I see no errors now! ... but I don't see any results on the front end? I've updated my question to explain. Cheers for clearing one issue though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

you need to pass the post in `get_field` in loop. otherwise it will get current page id

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $PostId = get_the_ID();
    $case_study_heading = get_field('case_study_heading', $PostId);
    $case_study_subheading = get_field('case_study_subheading', $PostId);
    $case_study_backgroung = get_field('case_study_background', $PostId);
    $case_study_play = get_field('case_study_play_button', $PostId);

    echo $case_study_heading;
} else {
    echo "no posts";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    $case_study_heading = get_field('case_study_heading');
    // etc (for brevity)

    echo $case_study_heading;
} else {
    echo "no posts";
}
```

then you have not included the loop, so your `get_field()`s will all be addressing the containing post/page and not the posts within the loop.

You would therefore also need to include the loop:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $case_study_heading = get_field('case_study_heading');
        // etc (for brevity)

        echo $case_study_heading;
    }
} else {
    echo "no posts";
}
```